# nodejs googleapis calendar.events key issue

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm attempting to fetch events from a users calendar with the nodejs googleapis package.  I'm using passport to log a user in with Google, and using the following scope:

```
scope = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
  'profile',
  'email'
],
```

This all seems to work fine, and passport receives the token, profile, etc...So then I attempt to fetch the calendar events like so:

```
module.exports = (token) => {
    const calendar = google.calendar({
      version: 'v3',
      auth: token
    });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
      maxResults: 10,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
    }, (err, events) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(events);
    });
  });
};
```

`token` that is passed into that function is the `accessToken` that I get during the passport login.  The error that I get after this is:

```
0|www      |   errors:
0|www      |    [ { domain: 'usageLimits',
0|www      |        reason: 'keyInvalid',
0|www      |        message: 'Bad Request' } ] }
```

Now, obviously, this suggests that I'm not using the key properly, but the examples I've been able to find show passing the access token in with the initial call to `google.calendar`.  Any ideas what I might be overlooking? Logging the token does yield the correct token in the console, so the token is getting in there properly.  Thanks you!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but can you try this github repo which mentions using PassportJS with Calendar API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was not properly implementing the use of refreshTokens.  The pattern I have now fetches a new token with every request using the refreshToken.

Comment: Can I get the code for it? I too am using Passport and Calendar APi